# Ubuntu 18.04.1 NordVPN does not operate correctly

Tags: 18.04, vpn

I'm relatively new to Linux \ Ubuntu so please excuse my ignorance. I've searched for this issue but can't find an answer which either applies to my scenario (or which I understand!).

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.01 desktop & tried to associate my existing NordVPN to it using OpenVPN.

Based on research I'd done I ran the following commands:

```
  sudo apt-get install openvpn
  sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
  sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc
  sudo apt-get install network-manager-pptp
  sudo service network-manager restart
```

These seemed to work but when I checked my VPN with WHATISMYIPPADDRESS.COM it displayed my full ISP IP details.

Having re-tried this several times I'd appreciate any help anyone can give.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try with `.ovpn` files sir?

Comment: Yes, I used the .ovpn files supplied by Nord.

Comment: i don't get your mean "does not operate correctly" sir, what steps you do sir?

Comment: Basically I entered the commends (above); clicked on 'Add VPN'; selected "Import from file"'; & selected the NordVPN ovpn file. Viewing the generated VPN (via the desktop GUI) shows the 'Gateway' address has been filled in; the 'Authentication Type' is set to 'Password'; & the CA certificate 'pem' file has been correctly picked up. (continued below)

Comment: I entered my supplier name & password into the dialog box & chose 'Store the password for this user only'. I saved this config & then enabled VPN. the VPN lock icon displays  in the top menu bar (which implies the VPN is working) but when I browse to whatismyipaddress.com it still shows my normal ISP details.

Comment: do you see icon vpn like "three-computer-triger-connected" is enabled sir?

Comment: did you check using tor-browser what that works sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to connect to NordVNP, depends if you have a free or a paid accout.

1. Using the command line interface:
   Download the application from here:
   https://support.nordvpn.com/#/Connectivity/Linux/1182453582/Installing-and-using-NordVPN-on-Linux.htm
   Follow the instructions and you succeed within minutes.
2. Using OpenVPN:
   This needs the password and username of a paid account.
   Instructions: 
   https://support.nordvpn.com/#/Connectivity/Linux/1061938702/How-to-connect-to-NordVPN-using-Linux-Network-Manager.htm

Answer (score 0):

NordVPN have changed the way they like their users to access their service.
Instead of using the Network Manager, or OVPN manual command line commands, they now supply an application which needs to be run on the command line.  They have not, yet, supplied a GUI for this application.

This is the NordVPN page describing how to install the app: https://nordvpn.com/download/linux/
After downloading the file:

```
sudo apt-get install {/path/to/}nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nordvpn
```

Here are the full instructions on the NordVPN website:
https://support.nordvpn.com/#/Connectivity/Linux/1182453582/Installing-and-using-NordVPN-on-Linux.htm